# The bundle “CheckoutTests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcuitest, uitest

I have started writing unit test for my app. After running test class(XCTest), build is getting success but test is getting fail with framework linking problem of the another target. That another target itself is building and testing successfully.

I have tried each and every solution available on internet but none of those suggestions are working for my problem. In shorts, I have tried Setting target of test in Podfile with inherit! :complete, set framework to Optional, Enabled Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries option under Build Options, checked IOS deployment target etc.

> **Logs are following:** 
>   The bundle “CheckoutTests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.
>
> Try reinstalling the bundle.
>   dlopen_preflight(/Users/..../Debugiphonesimulator/CheckoutTests.xctest/CheckoutTests): Library not loaded:@rpath/CleverTapSDK.framework/CleverTapSDK.
>
> Referenced from: /Users/.../DerivedData/.../Debug-iphonesimulator/CustomerAnalytics.framework/CustomerAnalytics.
>
> Reason: image not found)
>
> Program ended with exit code: 82

```
**Podfile:** 
>target 'Checkout' do

> project 'Projects/Checkout/Checkout.xcodeproj'>>
  pod 'SDWebImage',                       '3.8.2'
  target 'CheckoutTests' do
    inherit! :complete
  end
end
```

I want to run test pass without any framework linking problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your framework was not copied into the appropriate target. Check the build phases and make sure you are copying the built framework into the target output bundle.